# Automation of UAT based off Tableau Report

Tags: automated-testing, user-acceptance-testing

I am currently researching on behalf of a group that is manually carrying out UAT where they test the Tableau report against a day to day report (Excel based) within the business.

UAT is not passed unless data matches less than 1% to ensure all the business logic is captured in the day to day reports.

I was wondering if there are tools or methods that will enable this process to be automated as currently, the manual process is a time burden.

Comment: I know of 2 tools that can automate this. Kinesis for tableau - https://kinesis-ci.com/
and
BI Validator - http://www.datagaps.com/bi-validator/automate-tableau-testing
which are both paid. What I would like to know though, is if selenium or protractor can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few paid tools that do this:

- https://www.florencesoft.com/compare-excel-workbooks-differences.html
- http://www.suntrap-systems.com/ExcelDiff/
- http://www.formulasoft.com/excel-compare.html

If you have a versioned excel document:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-Spreadsheet-Compare-0E1627FD-CE14-4C33-9AB1-8EA82C6A5A7E

The free version that is a plugin to excel:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/spreadshcompare/

The manual way to manipulate excel and ease comparison through formulas:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Data-in-Excel

---

Good luck and I hope one of these methods works for you and your users.